How to connect trust wallet conection modal in mobile ethersjs?
I have an authorization web3  window but its only opens on desktop but not on mobile apps. How can I solve this problem ?
export const getSigner = async () => {   

    let provider;

    if(window.ethereum){
        provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    }

    await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    return signer;
}


Is it only a problem with trust wallet? Is metamask or any other wallet working?

It was not possible to check since the use of a trust wallet is required, I heard that the fact is that web3 does not work in mobile Chrome, can you suggest an approximate implementation using metamask

This old post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110913/cannot-connect-web3-within-metamask-browser-on-mobile makes it look like window.ethereum works with metamask and an unspecified browser, let's try to research limitations of window.ethereum and mobile browsers. Are you sure the users have the wallet installed?

Yes, if the trust application is installed on the phone, the application simply does not open
